# 40% of zeros of Riemann's Zeta function - question.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Conrey (1989) proved that at least 40% of zeros of the Riemann's zeta funvtion lie on critical lane. But what does exactly mean 40%? Cardinality of all RZF zeros is $\aleph_0$, and every infinite subset of a set of power $\aleph_0$ also has power $\aleph_0$.
Does that 40% mean that if we look at zeros with modulus $\leq M$ that $$\lim_{ M\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\text{zeros on critical lane with modulus} \leq M}{\text{all zeros with modulus} \leq M}\geq 0.4$$?

Comment: Yes, something close to that

Answer (score 3):

Was a comment but it got too long so made it an answer:

It is highly unlikely (on known density theorems) that the limit above is not $1$ so $100$% of the zeroes are expected to lie on the critical line regardless of the truth of RH (remembering that for infinite sets there is a major difference between all and $100$%).

So far we know the following three facts:

the number of critical zeroes up to imaginary value $T$ is ~$T \log T$ (Riemann von Mangoldt)

the number of trivial zeroes up to absolute value $T$ is $O(T)$ (trivial)

the number of possible zeroes in the strip $\frac{1}{2} < \sigma < \Re s <1$ is $O_{\sigma}(T)$ (there are actually much more refined but of course more difficult estimates depending on $\sigma$) (classical, maybe Bohr and/or Landau?)

it follows that we already know that for any $\frac{1}{2} < \sigma<1$,  $100$% of zeroes regarded as the limit above with zeroes up to some form of magnitude $T$ (and we can include the trivial ones here if we so wish and use $|s| \le T$ or not include them and use the more usual $|\Im s| \le T$) lie in the strip $1-\sigma < \Re s < \sigma$

Answer (score 2):

"For some $Y>0$, we count roots in the finite strip $\{x+\mathrm{i}y \mid 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } -Y < y < Y\}$.  Then look at what fraction of those are on the critical line or are far enough away from the critical line as we let $Y$ increase." from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2680126/123905
The bit about "that far away or farther" is meaningful in the context of Bohr and Landau's result, which is also discussed there.

This is largely equivalent to your formulation.

Comment: So is Corney's result that >=40% of all zeros lie on critical lane or that >=40% zeros in the critical strip lie on critical lane? On Polish wikipedia it is written that 40% of all zeros, not that 40% inside critical strip.

Comment: @MaciejFicek : 40% of zeroes in critical strip.  Nearly everyone ignores the "trivial zeroes" (on the negative real axis).

Comment: Thanks. Do You know also if he proved that that limes exists or he only proved that if it exists, than it must be >=40%, but not necessarily exist?

Comment: The paper is publicly available: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183554910  .  He shows the limit inferior (lim inf) of the ratio is $\geq 2/5$.  I don't know that anyone has shown the limit exists.  It would be *fascinating* if someone were to prove it did not.

Comment: Yeah, it would mean that Riemann's Hypothesis is not true :)